# MongoDB Aggregation - Flatten resultat

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, aggregate

```
db.collection.aggregate([
              ....
    { $group: {_id: "$data.r.id", "col": {$first: "$data.r"}}},
    {$project:{"o":{"$objectToArray":"$col"}}},
    {$unwind:"$o"},
    {$group:{"_id":null, "keys":{$addToSet:"$o.k"}}},
    {$project: {"keys":1, "_id": 0}},
    {$addFields: {res:{$map:{ input:"$keys", as: "a", in: {"_id":0,"label": "$$a"}}}}},
    {$project: {"res":1}}
])
```

With my MongoDB query, the output is:

```
{ 
  "res" : [
     {
         "_id" : 0.0, 
         "label" : "aaaa"
     }, 
     {
         "_id" : 0.0, 
         "label" : "bbbbb"
     }, 
     {
         "_id" : 0.0, 
         "label" : "ccccc"
     }
  ] 
}
```

and I try to output this:

```
{
    "_id" : 0.0, 
    "label" : "aaaa"
}, 
{
    "_id" : 0.0, 
    "label" : "bbbb"
}, 
{
    "_id" : 0.0, 
    "label" : "cccc"
}
```

so I added:

```
{$replaceRoot : {"newRoot": "$res"}}
```

but I got this error:

> ''newRoot' expression must evaluate to an object, but resulting value
> was: [{_id: 0, label: "aaaa"},{_id: 0, label: "bbbb"},{_id: 0, label:
> "cccc"}]

How can I remove the nested object "res" to return only the list/array of objects (id, label)?

Comment: Thinking you need `$unwind: $res` first before `$replaceRoot`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Re-write the answer from the comment to resolve the question.

You need to flatten the deconstruct `res` array first

```
{ $unwind: "$res" }
```

before replacing the input documents with

```
{
  $replaceRoot: {
    newRoot: "$res"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer was:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
              ....
    { $group: {_id: "$data.r.id", "col": {$first: "$data.r"}}},
    {$project:{"o":{"$objectToArray":"$col"}}},
    {$unwind:"$o"},
    {$group:{"_id":null, "keys":{$addToSet:"$o.k"}}},
    {$project: {"keys":1, "_id": 0}},
    {$addFields: {res:{$map:{ input:"$keys", as: "a", in: {"_id":0,"label": "$$a"}}}}},
    {$project: {"res":1}},
    {$unwind:"$res"},
    {$replaceRoot: {"newRoot": "$res"}}
])
```

thanks a lot